# Parsing the text with React from server with Draft.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, draftjs

I'm trying out Draft.js with my React application running with a GraphQL server. Currently I have a editor where I can type and add code blocks and submit it to the server. Here's the code for that:

```
const contentState = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent()

const { content } = this.state.values
console.log('raw', convertToRaw(contentState))

let response;
try {
  response = await this.props.mutate({
    variables: {
      content: JSON.stringify(contentState)
    },
  })
  console.log(response)
```

`response` gives me

[image]

And that's no good. I rather have the `convertToRaw(contentState)` since that gives me:

[image]

The reason why I'm not doing `convertToRaw(contentState)` at `mutate` is because it gives me this error:

**contentState.getBlockMap is not a function**

So my questions are how can I use the `convertToRaw` function when submitting the text to the server and how can I later parse the text on the frontend so it wont look like this:

[image]

Thanks for reading my question. All help is appreciated!

Have a great day.

Comment: Some things aren't completely clear so I'll take some guesses. Why don't you try doing `const rawContent = convertToRaw(contentState)` next to your first `console.log` and then use `content: JSON.stringify(rawContent)` when you pass `variables` to `mutate`?

Comment: @Rajit Sorry if I'm not too clear in this question. But currently I think the problems lays when I try to `parse` the text back to be "normal". Meaning not to have a JSON object. And I haven't figured out how to parse it. Thanks for replying!